# AngularJS $location.search() doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS 1.6.4

The url of my homepage is `http://localhost:8080/AsumForum/`

I am trying to display a success message if user has registered successfully to my web site. If the user is registered, I will redirect him to the home page, and my url looks like this: `http://localhost:8080/AsumForum/?registered=true`.

The thing is, $location.search() never finds registered=true. I have tried making $locationProvider compatible with HTML5, but that doesn't work either.

Here is my registration.js:

```
var app = angular.module('reg',[]);

app.controller('valid', ['$scope','$location','$http', 
function($scope,$location,$http){

   $scope.send = function(){
       var date = new Date();
       $scope.user.date=date.toString();
       $http({
           url: 'http://localhost:8080/AsumForum/webapi/users/register',
           dataType: 'json',
           method: 'POST',
           data: $scope.user,
           headers: {
               "Content-Type": "application/json"
           }
       }).then(function success(response){

            $scope.res = response.data;
            $scope.satus = response.status;
            console.log('RES: '+$scope.res+'\nSTATUS: '+$scope.status);
            window.location="http://localhost:8080/AsumForum/?registered=true";

        }, function error(response){

            $scope.res = response.statusText;
            console.log('Error: +'+$scope.res);
        });
    }
```

}]);

And here is my login.js

```
var app = angular.module('mainPage',[]);

app.controller('regsuc',['$scope','$location',function($scope,$location){
    $scope.message = '';
    var show = $location.search();
    for(var i in show){
        console.log(i);
    }
    if(show==true){
        $scope.message="Successfull registered! You can now log in.";
    }
}]);
```

Logs don't return anything. Using `console.log(show)` returns [object Object].

Do I really have to use routing to pass parameters, or can it be done like I tried?

**Note 1:** Redirecting with `$location.url('http://localhost:8080/AsumForum/?registered=true);` doesn't work for me.

**Note 2:** Using `location.search` instead of `$location.search` returns ?registered=true.

Comment: Is the controller `regsuc` getting accessed? If you put a console.log before `$scope.message = '';` do you see the log?

Comment: It is getting accessed, tested that like a milion times

Comment: What does `$location.absUrl()` return?

Comment: Without ?registered=true it returns `http://localhost:8080/AsumForum/`
With ?registered=true it returns `http://localhost:8080/AsumForum/?registered=true`

Comment: `$location.search()` returns an object containing the key/value pairs in the query string. The values themselves are strings. `if ($location.search().registered === 'true') { ... }`

Comment: Yes, but it returns nothing, it doesn't contain key registered.

Answer (score 3):

Just try the following

you have missed the parameter name in $location.search()

```
$location.search().registered
```

Comment: This returns undefined